# why do we give a string parameter in double quote instead of single quote in spring jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

For example, my statement is as follows:

```
dbConnection.update("insert into transaction (isrecovered) values(?)", new Object[]{"N"});
```

In above statement, why cannot we give "N" as 'N'?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a string is surrounded with double quotes.

A Java `char` is surrounded in single quotes.

A `String` is an `Object` (it is a sub-class) and the array must contain objects. A `char` is a primitive and not an `Object`.

Do not confuse the above, which concerns Java syntax only, with any of the columns in your data table. You may have columns that are CHAR or VARCHAR type. That's the database's way of specifying what's stored there.

Further, do not confuse the above with the content of the Java `String`s containing SQL statements. SQL is a different language than Java and uses different conventions. Different DataBase engines use either single or double quotes to surround a string constant in SQL. Plus it depends on the options selected. Typical common sense advice says to use single quotes unless your particular database and its settings mean you don't.

Comment: But my field is CHAR in  a table...then?

Comment: If your Java connector is smart enough, it may understand that a String with length 1 can be converted to char, but you may get an Exception otherwise

Comment: Buddy, that time exception was invalid conversion from UnsupportedException to UnSupportedException...what was that?

Answer (score 1):

There are **2 languages** mixed in this statement (**SQL and Java**) and each one has a different syntax.

Some languages accept String with single quote (like PHP and SQL) and some don't (like Java).

I suggest you use a safer solution like `PreparedStatement` where you could invoke `.setChar(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your update method accepts a String parameter and Strings are surrounded with double quotes in Java, not single quotes.
For the new Object[]{"N"} thing, Here also "N" is a String object, you can still pass 'N' to an array of objects cause they will be auto-boxed to Character Objects.

Comment: ok, got it..since Object array won't accept primitive values..thanx @javadev

Comment: this is not true, `Object[] array = new Object[] {'N'}` is legal because the primitive char is boxed into a Character object.

Comment: @Rodriguez, indeed, missed it!!